# Corda 3.3 nodes do not interact in docker network (yo-cordapp)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, corda

I am building a development network for Corda 3.3 using Docker.
There are 3 nodes (PartyA, PartyB, PartyC) and a notary running in different containers. My cordapp is the default Yo-App: https://github.com/roger3cev/yo-cordapp.

When I try sending a "Yo" from PartyA to PartyB, I do not get any reaction from PartyB. The cumulated logs just stop after this:

```
partya        | [INFO] 13:09:38+0000 [Node thread-1] flow.[83616806-a4ad-42b0-9971-9a0823bce6cc].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party O=PartyB, L=London, C=GB. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=3440335321282531945).
partya        | [INFO] 13:09:38+0000 [Messaging DLDRewETrQQASyFCr8arRT7PKymb77wj2rz1d3KVrMYvPb] messaging.P2PMessagingClient.createQueueIfAbsent - Create fresh queue internal.peers.DL6cscJ1aLiDExFxGHY2MoMuhDHx2gZBQZYgj5gNNttNap bound on same address
partya        | [INFO] 13:09:38+0000 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] bridging.BridgeControlListener.processControlMessage - Received bridge control message Create(nodeIdentity=DLDRewETrQQASyFCr8arRT7PKymb77wj2rz1d3KVrMYvPb, bridgeInfo=BridgeEntry(queueName=internal.peers.DL6cscJ1aLiDExFxGHY2MoMuhDHx2gZBQZYgj5gNNttNap, targets=[partyb:10002], legalNames=[O=PartyB, L=London, C=GB])) {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=eaa433d0-d02c-4350-8dbb-6da7c5c3709b, invocation_timestamp=2018-11-06T13:09:37.649Z, session_id=a05854b9-2bc2-426d-af65-3aa6c5b2d7be, session_timestamp=2018-11-06T13:06:32.553Z}
partya        | [INFO] 13:09:38+0000 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] peers.DL6cscJ1aLiDExFxGHY2MoMuhDHx2gZBQZYgj5gNNttNap -> partyb:10002:O=PartyB, L=London, C=GB.start - Create new AMQP bridge {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=eaa433d0-d02c-4350-8dbb-6da7c5c3709b, invocation_timestamp=2018-11-06T13:09:37.649Z, session_id=a05854b9-2bc2-426d-af65-3aa6c5b2d7be, session_timestamp=2018-11-06T13:06:32.553Z}
partya        | [INFO] 13:09:38+0000 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] netty.AMQPClient.start - connect to: partyb:10002 {actor_id=corda, actor_owningIdentity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, invocation_id=eaa433d0-d02c-4350-8dbb-6da7c5c3709b, invocation_timestamp=2018-11-06T13:09:37.649Z, session_id=a05854b9-2bc2-426d-af65-3aa6c5b2d7be, session_timestamp=2018-11-06T13:06:32.553Z}
partya        | [INFO] 13:09:38+0000 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Connected to partyb:10002
partya        | [INFO] 13:09:38+0000 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] O=PartyB, L=London, C=GB.channelActive - New client connection 122b0447 from partyb/172.18.0.3:10002 to /172.18.0.4:50744
partya        | [INFO] 13:09:38+0000 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.LoggingTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted - Check Server Certpath:
partya        |   C=GB,L=London,O=PartyB[484605596E5E68D784949F808BDF6BC1AE27E6E1] issued by C=GB,L=London,O=PartyB[null]
partya        |   C=GB,L=London,O=PartyB[0216D463A9D1253A112E96A7852347564333B32E] issued by CN=Corda Node Intermediate CA,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK[null]
partya        |   CN=Corda Node Intermediate CA,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK[EBEE2E30152940AE19981ED86FE37D7F07A2C213] issued by CN=Corda Node Root CA,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK[null]
partya        |   CN=Corda Node Root CA,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK[7CAEA9DFB948012B13890B9AE645851C39170773] issued by CN=Corda Node Root CA,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK[null]
partya        | [INFO] 13:09:38+0000 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] O=PartyB, L=London, C=GB.userEventTriggered - Handshake completed with subject: O=PartyB, L=London, C=GB
partya        | [INFO] 13:09:38+0000 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] peers.DL6cscJ1aLiDExFxGHY2MoMuhDHx2gZBQZYgj5gNNttNap -> partyb:10002:O=PartyB, L=London, C=GB.onSocketConnected - Bridge Connected
partya        | [INFO] 13:09:38+0000 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB.onConnectionLocalOpen - Connection local open org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.ConnectionImpl@53bbae2d
```

My node.conf reads:

```
myLegalName : "O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB"
p2pAddress : "partya:10002"
webAddress : "partya:10005"
devMode : true
rpcSettings = {
    address : "partya:10003"
    adminAddress : "partya:10004"
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        user=corda
        password=corda_initial_password
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
    }
]
detectPublicIp : false
```

What is the reason for not getting any reaction from PartyB?
Judging from the logs it all just stops after a successful handshake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Authentication was flawed in my network because the containers created their own nodeInfo-* files which did not match the nodeInfo-* files I provided in directory "additional-node-infos/".

---

After activating debug mode using command line argument "--logging-level DEBUG" I spotted the authentication error. For local testing I now do the following:

1. Share a docker volume between all containers mapping to directory "additional-node-infos"
2. Have the containers share their nodeInfo at startup.

This is the script I use for running corda containers in dev-mode:

```
#!/bin/sh

# If variable not present use default values
: ${CORDA_HOME:=/opt/corda}
: ${JAVA_OPTIONS:=-Xmx512m}

export CORDA_HOME JAVA_OPTIONS

cd ${CORDA_HOME}

### share the node-info with the other nodes via docker volume
java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar ${CORDA_HOME}/corda.jar --just-generate-node-info
cp -f nodeInfo-* additional-node-infos/

### usual start
java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar ${CORDA_HOME}/corda-webserver.jar 2>&1 &
java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar ${CORDA_HOME}/corda.jar --log-to-console 2>&1
```